# MySQL on Kubernetes - pod has unbound immeidate persistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes

I tried deploying MySQL on Kubernetes as mentioned in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/. But, running into the below error.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  27s (x6 over 72s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 99 times)
  Warning  FailedScheduling  0s (x14 over 94s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 100 times)
```

Not sure what is wrong with this?  Can i remove volumeClaimTemplates and create a separate persistentVolumeClaim?

Comment: what storage class are you using? `kubectl get storageclass`

Comment: the storage class is scaleio

Comment: Also, the output of `kubectl get pv` and `kubectl get pvc`

Answer (score 1):

In the doc its mentioned

> You need to either have a dynamic PersistentVolume provisioner with a
>   default [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/), or [statically provision](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#provisioning) [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#provisioning)
>   yourself to satisfy the [PersistentVolumeClaims](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) used here